# Two for loops in R

Tags: r, loops

I want to simulate daily values from monthly values following the formula: 
V(d)=V(m)*(1+noise), noise is normally distributed with mean 0 and standard deviation 0.18)

I have monthly values in 12x1 matrix called wind.m and days in each month in another 12x1 matrix called day.I use two for loops:

```
for (i in (1:12)) {
  for (j in (1:12)){
    A<-wind.m[i,]*(1+rnorm(day[j,],0,0.18))
  }
  print(A)
}
```

the result of this code simulates 12 sets of 31 daily values, which is wrong (Feb has 28 days, April, June have 30 days etc) I'm not sure how to fix my codes.

the following is the data used:

```
> wind.m
      [,1]
 [1,] 2.78
 [2,] 2.93
 [3,] 3.09
 [4,] 3.11
 [5,] 3.44
 [6,] 3.44
 [7,] 3.71
 [8,] 3.86
 [9,] 4.05
[10,] 4.08
[11,] 4.22
[12,] 4.30
> day
      [,1]
 [1,]   31
 [2,]   28
 [3,]   31
 [4,]   30
 [5,]   31
 [6,]   30
 [7,]   31
 [8,]   31
 [9,]   30
[10,]   31
[11,]   30
[12,]   31
```

Comment: I cant even see how you are generating blocks of 31.. it looks to me like you are doing blocks of 12 days.

Comment: This makes very little sense, especially without your `day` and `wind.m` data... how do you get 31 from anything?  is it in `day`?

Comment: "and days in each month in another 12x1 matrix called day." Shouldn't your days matrix be 12x31?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could leave the loops out AND solve your problem AND learn a bit about R vectorization in three easy steps.

Setup:

```
wind.m <- c(2.78, 2.93, 3.09, 3.11, 3.44, 3.44, 
            3.71, 3.86, 4.05, 4.08, 4.22, 4.30)
day <- c(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 
         31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31)
```

Then use `rep` to expand your monthly means into daily values for a year.

```
day_means <- rep(wind.m, times = day)
```

Then generate your simulated values.

```
A <- rnorm(length(day_means), mean = day_means , sd=0.18)
```

A is your simulated data.

Answer (score 1):

No need for nested loops. I think you can use `mapply` in this case.

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(month = month.abb,
                 numb_day = c(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31,
                 31, 30, 31, 30 , 31),
                 wind_m = rnorm(12, mean = 20, sd = 5))

addNoise <- function(n, x) x * (1 + rnorm(n, 0, 0.18))

wind_d <- mapply(addNoise, df$numb_day, df$wind_m)
str(wind_d)
## List of 12
##  $ : num [1:31] 21.5 27.5 35.5 38.6 21.6 ...
##  $ : num [1:28] 21.7 11.3 15 16.2 12 ...
##  $ : num [1:31] 13.7 20.8 17.2 27.5 27.1 ...
##  $ : num [1:30] 26.3 14.2 20.2 23.1 17.1 ...
##  $ : num [1:31] 17.3 22.5 22 26.1 25.6 ...
##  $ : num [1:30] 20.8 12.8 13.1 15.5 18.3 ...
##  $ : num [1:31] 32.1 19.7 30.5 28 32.4 ...
##  $ : num [1:31] 19.5 19.5 20.1 21.6 19.1 ...
##  $ : num [1:30] 35.5 34.1 26.7 32.2 25.3 ...
##  $ : num [1:31] 22.7 19.5 15.8 21.7 24.3 ...
##  $ : num [1:30] 20.2 32.2 23.7 32.3 24.3 ...
##  $ : num [1:31] 41.2 31.1 28.4 35.7 28.7 ...
```

**EDIT : Using the data of the OP**

```
set.seed(123)
wind_d <- mapply(addNoise, day, wind.m)
## List of 12
##  $ : num [1:31] 2.5 2.66 3.56 2.82 2.84 ...
##  $ : num [1:28] 2.77 3.4 3.39 3.36 3.29 ...
##  $ : num [1:31] 3.21 3.3 2.81 2.9 2.52 ...
##  $ : num [1:30] 3.67 3.42 3.24 2.76 3.87 ...
##  $ : num [1:31] 3.51 2.85 3.14 3.28 4.58 ...
##  $ : num [1:30] 3.92 3.65 2.82 3.37 3.27 ...
##  $ : num [1:31] 4.55 3.48 3.13 3.55 3.58 ...
##  $ : num [1:31] 4.72 3.5 3.17 5.02 3.55 ...
##  $ : num [1:30] 3.22 3.92 5.44 3.98 3.06 ...
##  $ : num [1:31] 3.06 4.7 3.75 4.21 4.13 ...
##  $ : num [1:30] 3.89 4.47 2.69 4.38 5.16 ...
##  $ : num [1:31] 4.59 2.71 3.24 4.14 4.97 ...
```

Comment: Anyway I can save the result into 365x1 vector?

Comment: @user2472273 Yes, you can. Just do `unlist(wind_d)`